# Using CStr to loop

Tags: excel, vba

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[11],3)"

The above works the way that I want it to.  But when I change it (below) so that I can loop through the file with my looping variable being 'r' I get 'expected end of statement'. Is there something basically wrong with what I am trying to do?

'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(!R" & CStr(r) & "C11",3)"

Comment: Do you need to loop? You can use `Range("A1:A99").FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[11],3)"` .

Comment: Escape the `"` characters?

Comment: @Mephy is right you are not escaping the `!R"` bit. You missed the parenthesis `"`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to store the left three characters from the column 11 away from the active cell.

If you loop through the rows (R), all you will do is replace the formula in the active cell r number of times. The final r will finally be set as the formula in the active cell.

Are you trying to go through each of the rows and saving the left three characters from the column 11 to the right?

If so, you might try ActiveCell.Offset(row,col). 
You can loop through the rows with:
          ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).activate

You can store the formula in the original column with:
          ActiveCell.Formula = "=LEFT(RC[11],3)"

If you keep track of the number of times that you loop, you can return to the starting point with:
          ActiveCell.OffSet(-(myRowCount),0).Activate

You can also test ActiveCell.value to see if you are at the end of your data.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up a few characters. Here is the solution:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(R[" & CStr(r) & "]C[11],3)"
```